# Python filtering list by truthiness

Tags: python

I am somewhat new to python and have been working with lists of strings like the first list and am looking to filter it down to only the truthy values as depicted in the second.

```
l = ['value1', 'value2', '', None, 'value3']
l = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

I have been doing it the following ways previously (the second more recently)

```
new_l = filter(lambda x: x, l)
new_l = filter(bool, l)
```

Is there a more pythonic approach to this solution?

Comment: I think your `new_l = filter(bool, l)` approach is the best option here. The intent is quite clear, and less wordy than using a list comprehension.

Comment: `new = [element for element in l if element]`

Answer (score 24):

If first argument is `None` [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) automatically removes all the elements that evaluate to `False` in boolean context. I would consider that the most pythonic approach:

```
>>> filter(None, [1, 3, 0, 5, 3])
[1, 3, 5, 3]
```

Excerpt from Python docs:

> Construct a list from those elements of iterable for which function returns true. iterable may be either a sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If iterable is a string or a tuple, the result also has that type; otherwise it is always a list. If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.

Alternative option would be list comprehension on Python 2 and generator expression on Python 3. The benefit of using them would be that they behave the same no matter what Python version you are using unlike [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter) that returns `iterator` on Python 3 instead of a list:

```
>>> l = [1, 3, 0, 5, 3]
>>> [x for x in l if x]
[1, 3, 5, 3]
>>> list(x for x in l if x)
[1, 3, 5, 3]
```

Comment: I think `filter(None, iterable)` is not very intuitive if you read that for the first time. I would say `filter(bool, iterable)` is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Most pythonic way.

Use **list comprehension**:

```
l = ['value1', 'value2', '', None, 'value3']
new = [element for element in l if element]

print(new)
#['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

No need for `filter`.

Comment: I don't get why this answer is downvoted. IMO this is much more readable than top comment and is in fact recommended by the majority of the community.

Comment: Probably because of your headline. Something like 'I think this is the most pythonic way:' would have been much better :)

Comment: Tthe existing answer, posted three years prior to this one, already covers using list comps.  This answer doesn't provide any additional value, some might downvote on that basis.